# ERROR: only one relationship type is allowed for MERGE open cypher query agensgraph

Tags: cypher, relationship, agens-graph

Is the below realtionship creation allowed in open cypher query I am trying this in agensgraph,

```
MATCH (mc: mat_comp)
MATCH (p:plant)
MATCH (mb: material)
WHERE mc.component = mb.material and mc.plant=p.b_plant
MERGE (mc) <- [ comp_2_p] - ( p)
;
ERROR: only one relationship type is allowed for MERGE
```

What mistake I am doing... because mat_comp and plant nodes has plant as common mat_comp and material nodes has material as common
    mat_comp
    has material column
    plant column

```
p: plant
mb:
material colum

MATCH (mc: mat_comp)
MATCH (p:plant)
MATCH (mb: material)
WHERE mc.comp = mb.material and mc.plant=p.b_plant
RETURN mc.comp, mb.material, mc.plant, p.b_plant;
comp | material | plant | b_plant
------------+------------+-------+--------------
"10" | "10" | "33" | "33"

=# \d material
material | character varying(50) | | | |
b_plant | character varying(50) |

=# \d mat_comp
material | character varying(50) | | | |
comp | character varying(50) | | | |
plant | character varying(50) | | | |

-# \d plant
--------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+-------------
b_plant | character varying(50) |
```

Comment: Is this related to hyper edges

[link] (https://dzone.com/articles/modelling-data-with-hypergraphs)
[link] (https://markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/22/neo4j-modelling-hyper-edges-in-a-property-graph/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your query has a simple mistake in MERGE clause.

To cut to the point. You can use this query

```
MERGE (mc) <- [:comp_2_p] - (p)
```

The mistake is colon.
The word after the colon is type of component (such as node and edge).
The word before the colon is like a pronoun in Cypher clause (I don't know its exact name.).

If you still have another ERROR using above query, you should check whether the elabel "comp_2_p" is declared or not.